# Drawing dynamically created SVG on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, mathjax

I define simple svg as a string, create img, initialize img.src by this string and then draw this img on my canvas. But canvas after all is empty (((.

This is my code:

```
        var svgData = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="110"><rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>'

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))) );
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
```

If I try to append `img` directly to page it displays perfectly.

Also if I simply put a text on `ctx` with `FillText` it displays correctly. From this I conclude that canvas works well.

Comment: Does the SVG data have width and height attributes on its root element that are not percentages?

Comment: Robert, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8.034ex" height="5.127ex"....

Comment: Ahh, you've not waited for the image's onload event before calling drawImage.

Comment: I tried this with img.onload = function() {ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); } But it did not help

Comment: you'll need to provide a [mcve] then i.e. something we can run with an example SVG file. In fact maybe you could simplify the problem by ignoring mathjax? Does just loading a test SVG with a simple rect in it work in your set up?

Comment: Robert, thank you. You were right. The point is that I used my canvas before it were filled with img.